# Cannot include header from another package

Tags: ros, headers, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package `my_lib`, that contains `Parameters.h` in he include folder, which I need to include in another package `my_main`. I am following this answer to do so:
https://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/
But I get

```
fatal error: my_lib/Parameters.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

when I run `catkin_make`.
I can see `Parameters.h` appear successfully in `catkin_ws/install/include/my_lib` after I ran `catkin_make install`.
In my_main package i did the following:

`package.xml`: added

```
<build_depend>my_lib</build_depend>
<exec_depend>my_lib</exec_depend>
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ...(other packages used in my_main)  
  my_lib )
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system) 
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES my_main 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ...(other packages used in my_main) my_lib
  DEPENDS system_lib)
include_directories(   include  
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
  add_executable(my_main_node src/my_main_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_main_node   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
install(DIRECTORY
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/   DESTINATION
  ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION} 
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"   PATTERN
  ".svn" EXCLUDE )
```

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285472/cannot-include-header-from-another-package/) by [s_lana](https://answers.ros.org/users/31895/s_lana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) on 2018-03-14**:
Is there a difference between "my_lib" and the `my2_lib` that appears in your CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [s_lana](https://answers.ros.org/users/31895/s_lana/) on 2018-03-19**:
No, that was just a typo during copying and renaming, it is all the same node. Sorry about that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should make sure of the following:

1. The CMakeLists.txt of the my_lib package has `catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include...)`, `include_directories(include...)`, and the `install(...)` function call inside
2. Parameters.h is in `<workspace>/src/my_lib/include/my_lib/`. Notice the two occurrences of "my_lib"
3. Relevant files in the my_main package have the correct include statement `#include "my_lib/Parameters.h"`

---

Originally posted by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) with karma: 229 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5